# ZedGraphControl constructor suddenly takes a lot of memory

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015, zedgraph

I have a `WPF` application that I've been using about 1 year ago. Suddenly it started taking a lot of time to start when running it from **VS2015** (around 5 minutes).

I checked the task manager and it seems that the application's instance is taking **8,500 MB** from memory on startup, while decreasing to around **3,900 MB** later.

I created a release folder and tried it on several PCs and it worked fine. It seems that this problem is only on my PC.

**EDIT**

I started debugging my program after `InitializeComponent()` and found out that using `ZedGraphControl zedGraph = new ZedGraphControl();` is the one causing this problem. I tried to run old solutions that have been working before and now I have the same problem on them.

Note that I have been using `ZedGraphControl` in many projects and even in this project but this behavior suddenly appeared.

Comment: Check your debugger configuration, maybe you are collecting debugging data or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your Windows Update History if you have installed the Cumulative Update KB5001337 (for Windows 10). In my case, that was the culprit. Uninstalling KB5001337 should help (at least temporary).
Updating Windows 10 to version 20H2 will also solve the problem.

Comment: This might be the problem. I just checked and this update was installed on April 18 which is almost when this started happening. Though I am not able to uninstall it. It says security update for Microsoft windows kb5001337 is required by your computer and cannot be uninstalled. How did you manage to uninstall it.

Comment: Go to "View update history", then press on the "Unistall updates" button. A list with all the updates will appear. Select KB5001337 and press "Unistall" button. Maybe you should check if you have an admin account if this doesn't work.

Comment: Any updates on the topic, @DoubleH? If you think the provided answer helped you, please mark the answer as Accepted.

Comment: This was definitely the problem but until this moment I haven't been able to uninstall this update. I have an admin account but this update in particular doesn't show the uninstall button when I press on it. Unlike other updates.

Comment: It says: security update for Microsoft windows (KB5001337) is required by your computer and cannot be uninstalled. I tried to uninstall it using ```wusa /uninstall /kb:5001337```

Comment: For me it was pretty straightforward to uninstall it. One other thing that you can do, instead of that, is to update you Windows 10 to version 20H2. That will also fix the issue.

Comment: I updated my windows to the 20H2 version and everything is back to normal again. Thanks a lot it was a pain dealing with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed the nuget package [ZedGraph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ZedGraph/), you could try the following:

**1)** clean nuget caches, delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages` and also delete the folder `<solution_folder>\packages`

after that, run `update-package -reinstall` under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console**

**2)** close VS, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution folder, `bin` and `obj` folder and then restart your project to test again.

**3)** disable any third party extensions under Extensions-->Manage Extensions-->Installed.

**4)** reset vs settings under Tools-->Import and Export Settings--> Reset vs settings

**5)** type `devenv /safemode` under Developer Command prompt for VS to start a new pure VS to test again.

Comment: All your suggestions are VS related. I tried older versions of my UI where I am sure that this issue wasn't there, and I faced the same problem.